# vectorized an arbitrary function

Tags: plotting

We wish to draw a plot of `Sin[x]` function associated with a series of vectors stemming from horizontal axes and end to the mentioned function. Same as:

[image]

where `\Pi/n` is the distance between each vector.

I do not know how do I draw vectors, while I simply can draw the `Sin[x]`. Of course, we are not restricted to the `Sin[x]` function. We may have any arbitrary function instead of `Sin[x]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
f[x_] := Tanh[x];
t = Table[
   Arrow[{{x, 0}, {x, f[x]}}], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/12}];
Plot[f[x]
 , {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}
 , PlotStyle -> {Thin, Black}
 , AspectRatio -> 3/10
 , ImageSize -> Large
 , Epilog -> {Red, Arrowheads[0.02], t}
 ]
```

[image]

For Sin[x];

[image]

---

For functions with a wide y-plotrange, the arrowheads may start to look ugly where it hugs the x-axis. In that case, `t` can be slightly modified. A general solution may be elusive as the plot range determines it.

```
f[x_] := x^3 + 1;
t = Table[
   If[Abs[f[x]] > 40, Arrow[{{x, 0}, {x, f[x]}}]], {x, -2 \[Pi], 
    2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/12}];
```

[image]