# Why PlotMarkers change direction inside Show?

Tags: plotting

I was trying to answer this [vectorized an arbitrary function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/260936/vectorized-an-arbitrary-function)  using  `DiscretePlot` with `PlotMarkers`, then noticed that the plot markers turn around when adding the plots inside Show instead of remaining vertical.

Is this known issue and is this how it is supposed to work?

For example

```
p3 = DiscretePlot[Sin[k], {k, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledUpTriangle]"}];
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But notice that the little triangles at the end of the lines now turn around when adding this plot inside `Show` with another normal plot

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = DiscretePlot[Sin[k], {k, -Pi, 0, Pi/5}, PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledDownTriangle]"}]
p3 = DiscretePlot[Sin[k], {k, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledUpTriangle]"}]
Show[p1, p2, p3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the plotmarkers how they all sloped and no long vertical. Is there a way to keep them vertical?

V 13.0 on windows 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[FilledUpTriangle]", FontSize -> 10]}`

[image]

But with the sizes modified in plotmarkers:

`PlotMarkers -> {Style["\[FilledDownTriangle]", FontSize -> 30]}`

[image]

My conclusion is that it is an **optical illusion**.

---

**EDIT**

Had these polygons been of a slightly different shape then we wouldn't have had as much fun.

`Graphics@Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1.5, 0.3}, {1.5, 0.3}, {3, 0}, {1.5, 3}}]`

[image]

Comment: omg, it was all optical illusion then!  I thought it was a bug :)